# How to get android app version with firebase fcm token from server side

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-tools

I need my android app version at server side for those older app versions which are already on user's devices.I can't change android app code but can change server-side API code.I am using firebase for notification basically I have fcm token from where I want to retrieve app version.
PS: I want to filter notifications like a  notification should be pushed to version 2.2 but not 2.1

Answer (score 1):

You use the [InstanceID](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#get_information_about_app_instances) that you got from your app for push notifications, your server can then check each one to get information